# Yii2 $model->_attributes assignment does not work in new version

Tags: php, yii2, getter-setter

I inherited a project that was created with Yii2, ver. 2.0.4, with the task to update said project to a more current version of Yii2 (2.0.15) because of the incompatibility of the older one with PHP 7.2+.

I noticed that there is a lot of use of assigning arrays to a model:

```
$model->_attributes = $array;
```

With the new version this results in an exception

```
'yii\base\UnknownPropertyException' with message 'Setting unknown property: app\models\model::_attributes'
```

For the time being I created a workaround with the following function:

```
function customSetAttributes(&$model, $array) {
    foreach($model->attributeLabels() as $model_key => $model_label) {
        if(!isset($array[$model_key])) continue;
        $model->$model_key = $array[$model_key];
    }
}
```

Also, the getter function now has a similar issue.

What I would like to know:

- Was this type of assignment never intended in the first place (and I just haven't found the previous developer's code that enables it)? I skimmed over the Yii2 changelog but didn't notice anything related.
- Is there a way to "salvage" the previous behaviour so I don't have to replace each occurence with my workaround function?

Comment: this was never used like above even in the version you specified are those actual `controllers` under the `app/controllers` directory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ActiveRecord::$_attributes` was always private and never should be used in this way. I guess that previous developer edited framework core files in `vendor` directory and make this property protected/public.

You may try to emulate this behavior by creating  virtual attribute using getter and setter:

```
public function get_attributes() {
    return $this->getAttributes();
}

public function set_attributes($values) {
    $this->setAttributes($values, false);
}
```

But this will not always work and it is more like an ugly hack to make crappy code work. I strongly suggest to fix code to use `setAttributes()` instead of `_attributes`.

Also you should compare `yii2` package from `vendor` directory with source from https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-framework/releases/tag/2.0.4 - you may find more places where core was edited.

Comment: Thanks, so far I got by using setAttributes() and getAttributes().